# int b = 1 / 0.00001 doesn't give 100000

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, multiplication

I don't understand how C++ cannot make simple calculations like a simple calculator. I have code producing wrong results with double division and multiplication. An example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    double a = 0.00001;
    int b = 1/a;
    std::cout <<b<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives 99999 when it's supposed to give 100000. How can I have the right result?

Windows 7 64 bit, MSVC2012

Edit: Thank you for the explanation. I deduct that to solve my problem I have to round it before casting to int. I wonder if this is the default way of doing it as this kind of error doesn't seem acceptable to any program based on decimal calculations.

Comment: there is a type casting problem

Comment: it's because b is int type variable...declare b as double type and see...

Comment: @KhairulBasar Nope, that's not the problem at all

Comment: then what's the problem ?  @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Also note that 0.0001 does not have a finite representation in the binary floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @user In fact `a` is equal to `0.00001 00000 00000 00000 08180 30539 14031 30954 58623 13825 63710 21270 75195 3125`  http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.00001  Once you know the true value of `a` it is easy to see why `b` is not what you expected it to be.

Comment: You can use a round function before the cast.

Comment: No, rounding is not the right way to deal with decimals. The right way is to use a decimal data type rather than a binary data type.

Comment: I would reccomend [boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
double a = 0.00001;
```

Floating point numbers like `0.00001` cannot be represented precisely using `double`. `a` is actually a little bit bigger than `0.00001`. `1/a` therefore, is a little smaller than `100000`, casting it to `int` truncated to `99999`.

Comment: So the answer is to avoid casting to int?

Comment: @user3023605 Casting `1.99` to `int` would result as `1`. A better alternative is to use a round function.

Comment: No, rounding is not a good option. The "right" solution is to use a decimal data type that can represent the values exactly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know it's not "right", but better in practice comparing to casting. You are absolutely right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question uses `double`, a compact representation on 64 bits with, in most processors, hardware-accelerated basic operations and, on most operating systems, excellent implementations for elementary functions. There is absolutely no indication in the question that a decimal datatype with none of these advantages is an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: @PascalCuoq It depends entirely on the application, a critical fact that you have completely neglected to consider.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Did I say something akin to “No, rounding is not a good option. The "right" solution is …”?

Comment: @PascalCuoq The asker said "program based on decimal calculations" which seems quite clear to me.